# What exactly is 'Jsoup.connect(String url)'?

Tags: java, android, http, connection, jsoup

What I mean is; does the method `connect(String url)` in 'Jsoup'-static-class contain  in its' source-code a call to a native http-client such as `HttpURLConnection`?
Or is it entirely it's own thing?
If the latter, is it wise to use it in an Android environment?? 
Because it's recommended to use either Google-client or Java's-http-url-connection, in such a case.

Comment: Since [JSoup is open source](http://github.com/jhy/jsoup/), why not look for yourself?

Comment: It is?? didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

`Jsoup#connect` just checks if the URL is valid.

It uses its own `HttpConnection` class and returns a `Connection` object also from `Jsoup`.

You should maybe look at the JavaDoc for [`Document`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/).

Answer (score 0):

Well... it appears it does! Thus it can work in Android.

[image: :)]